# How to find nearest line from point using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, postgis-2.0, linestring

I have a table of Roads in PostGIS which geometry is "**geometry(MultiLineString,4326)**".

Its attribute are

> gid   osm_id  name    ref type    oneway  bridge  maxspeed    geom

Now i want to know the closest Road from latitude and longitude.

Also I want to set some distance from that **Line/Road** like **20m** both side and if the point is within that distance then it should give the name of that line else not.

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT name,ref,type,ST_Distance(ST_Buffer(r.geom,20),ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lon, lat),4326)) 
FROM roads r 
ORDER BY 4 ASC 
LIMIT 1;
```

For point in lon/lat coordinates:

```
SELECT name,ST_Distance(r.geom,ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lon, lat),4326)) FROM roads r ORDER BY 2 ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: @VldimirNaumov 
Both query are not working for me. Not giving the correct result.
I am more interested in second query as i want to pass the co-ordinate directly into SQL Query as well as distance of 20m or less or much on lines both side.

Does ST_ClosedPoint or ST_Intersects Query work?

how to use it?

Comment: There is no such function as ST_ClosedPoint in PostGIS. Please provide MWE that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I mean ST_Closestpoint will work ? How to use it? What is MWE ?

Comment: Minimal working example, e.g. provide SQL code that you are trying to execute. ST_ClosestPoint returns geometry, consult http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_ClosestPoint.html

Comment: SELECT name,ref,type,ST_Distance(r.geom,ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(75.252398, 19.905008),4326)) FROM roads r ORDER BY 2 ASC LIMIT 1;

name ref type   st_distance
NULL .  tertiary 7.58381841503622

Its should give the "ref" ==> NH211 but giving the wrong result

Comment: Try this 'SELECT ref,ST_Distance(r.geom,ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(75.252398, 19.905008),4326)) FROM roads r ORDER BY 2 ASC LIMIT 1;'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6509/discussion-between-vladimir-and-sandeep)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a little bit late.
This should work for the first part of your answer:

```
WITH objects AS
    (SELECT
        name,
        (ST_Dump(roads.geom)).geom AS geometries
    FROM roads),
point AS
    (SELECT
        'SRID=4326;POINT(long lat)'::geometry AS point
    );

SELECT DISTINCT ON
    (ST_Distance(point, geometries)),
    objects.name
FROM objects, point
    ORDER BY ST_Distance(point, geometries)
    LIMIT 1;
```

At first you dump the objects from a multilinestring and then you calculate the distance between your point and the dumped linestring.`SELECT DISTINCT ON` removes duplicate rows from your result set. Ordering by the distance und limiting by 1 the name of your nearest road appears.

For long and lat you have to define coordinate values.

Comment: `DISTINCT ON` and `LIMIT 1` are redundant, since the result will only be 1 row